# database query optimization mySQL

Tags: mysql

Hello was wondering what the better approach is: the target database will only have about 100,000 rows

To have one table like below:

### AllCars

```
ID | Car_Name |    Car_Model    | Car_Type  | Car_Features | Car_Location
______________________________________________________________________
1  |  Nissan  | Ultima Explorer |   4D      | Airbag Power | TX
```

**SQL:** `Select 'X' from AllCards where Car_Model LIKE '%ultima%';`

or to break it up into many tables

### Car_Types

```
ID | Car_Model |
----------------
1  | Nissa Ultima |
```

and write joins:

**SQL:**

```
   SELECT'X' from Car_Types c 
     JOIN AllCars a 
     ON a.ID = c.ID  
     WHERE Car_Model = 'Ultima';
```

Comment: You should follow normalization principles when deciding whether to have one table or multiple.

Comment: The condition `LIKE '%ultima%'` forces MySQL to check all records in the table `AllCars`. But if you'll normalize database, possible `Car_Types` will have far fewer records than 100,000.

Comment: you're right i was just wondering in terms of efficient how much better the join was than the like.

Comment: Year, make, model, style - JOINs make this better.  Normalize and measure; denormalize only when performance dictates.  100K rows isn't a lot for a properly indexed schema.

Comment: I agree with duffymo. In this case, only when you get to multiple options for a vehicle, make sense, but things of only one available  per car (4-cyl, 6-cyl, 8-cyl, color, doors, fabric), but other thing that could be part of a "package" where individual components may be 2-3 vs 10 (such as electronic features) would go into a secondary features table per specific car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused.  The two queries are not the same.  In one case:

```
where Car_Model LIKE '%ultima%'
```

And in the other:

```
WHERE Car_Model = 'Ultima'
```

If you think that `'Ultima'` is a valid value for `car_model`, I would suggest that you store `'Ultima'` in the field, with nothing else.  Perhaps you should have a multi-part identifier for the model.

In any case, it doesn't make a big difference whether you store the raw data in one table or whether you use a reference table -- so long as you store the value consistently.  The "consistently" often leads to using a reference table approach, which would be the second approach.  The key, though, is separating out the different components so you can use equality for the comparison rather than wildcards.

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff. sorry to disturb you from here. I am in critical situation to handle on sql module. I have updated my question here. please provide me a suggestion on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664546/linear-regression-analysis-for-date-field-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

It is almost always better to normalize your data.
However, you must ensure that you are not performing joins for even the most frequent queries.

There is no right or wrong answer to your question. It all depends on your use case, what kind of data you are going to store, how frequent it will be queried and how it would be queried, meaning what are the fields queried for most frequently.
So it would be better if you would provide more details about the nature and frequency of your queries.